# My chrome extension wont block mature websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Ok so I am trying to get a chrome extension to block mature websites but for some reason it is giving me an error. Here is the error: "Unchecked runtime.lastError: '*://*.youtube.com' is not a valid URL pattern." and here is the code:

```
{
    "name": "Video Testing",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Video testing extention",
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

here is background.js

```
const defaultFilters = [
    "*://*.youtube.com"
]

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return { cancel: true}},
    { urls: defaultFilters },
    ["blocking"]
)
```

So i hope someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: You maybe want `*://*.youtube.com/*`   But I wound't class youtube as a whole as mature content..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a forward slash at the end of the URL. The provided code in the question would not work for me until I added it, and the error appears to come back without it.

```
const defaultFilters = ["*://*.youtube.com/"]
```

As stated above, you'll want to use the below format if you wish to block all associated youtube URLs (such as video or channel links) as opposed to just youtube.com

```
const defaultFilters = ["*://*.youtube.com/*"]
```

Comment: I was just trying out if this can work to block inappropriate mature content for my little sister so I used youtube.com as a placeholder for mature websites